# Using multiple programs in one solution

Tags: c#, console-application, project, solution

I've been writing a game for not so long now, but the code is already getting incredibly messy, because the full game is one program in my solution. Is there a way for me to split my game into multiple programs, like subroutines, but every program has its own tab within the solution? (I'm working in Visual Studio) If there indeed is a way to do that, how would I do that? I'm still a beginner, so it would be a great help if you would explain it a bit more thoroughly than usual. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Yes, move your non-ui code into one or more class library projects, and reference those class libraries from your main project. While you're at it, add a Unit Test project and add unit tests to test the classes you moved to the class libraries.

Comment: You need to look into classes and methods and get your head around object oriented programming.

Comment: Alternatively to my previous suggestion (and probably better to start with) you can create subfolders within your project, and use those to group related classes. (I'm assuming you have already broken up your code into a number of different classes. If you haven't done that yet, you certainly need to start with that!)

Answer (score 2):

Need to think the difference between solution and project.

Solution is the entire code that solves the problem you have.

Project is a part of a solution.

Segment out your code into projects.  UI in one project, 'Common' stuff in another, Back-end in another, etc.

You can have the projects reference the other projects they need to get the job done (just can't have Circular references, ie. A->B->A).